# Как удалить символ из строки по индексу

Tags: python, строки, char

Есть строка `'1234567'`, хочу удалить из нее символ по индексу, например под номером `2` Тоесть в результате должно остаться только `124567`

Comment: `s = s[:i] + s[i+1:]` ?

Comment: [How to delete a character from a string using Python - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559559/how-to-delete-a-character-from-a-string-using-python)

Comment: @MaxU Пожалуйста, оформите как ответ, это работает!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться срезами:

```
index = 2
s = s[:index] + s[index+1:]
print(s)
```

Результат:

```
124567
```

Comment: А куда `i = 2` пропало после правки?

Comment: @0xdb, спасибо, вернул на место ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант:

```
def remove_character(string, index):
    s = list(string) # конвертируем в список
    del s[index] # удаляем элемент с индексом index
    return "".join(s) # соединяем в строку и возвращаем результат в место вызова
```

Answer (score 2):

Только как шутка - но работает:

```
s = '1234567'
s = "".join([char for num, char in enumerate(s) if num != 2])
```

Comment: А потом вашу «шутку» будут копипастить и выкатывать в продакшен stackoverflow-driven разработчики :)

Answer (score 0):

```
string='12345'
lst=list(string)
lst.pop(2)
lst="".join(lst)
print(lst)
```

Перевести в список, методом pop удалить ненужный элемент по индексу и обратно в строку

Comment: 1. Будет ошибка во второй строчке. 2. Не следует использовать ``list`` в качестве имени переменной или функции.

Comment: 1. Ошибки не наблюдаю. 2. Такое имя использую просто для наглядности только в этом примере

Comment: Ошибка будет уже в первой строчке – ValueError empty separtor

Comment: Я сомневаюсь, что вы запускали этот код. Ошибка ``ValueError: empty separator``. И в 2.х и в 3.х. Да и  последняя строчка выведет совсем не результат предпоследней. 2. Не надо использовать такие имена даже просто для наглядности.

Comment: Код подправил, действительно немного не так написал, но не понимаю где вы все видите ошибку особенно в первой строчке. Во второй ее тоже нет. Создаём из строки список по разделителю "", то есть включая в список каждый символ строки

Comment: @FedotSoldier Попробуйте в любом REPLе выполнить команду `'123'.split("")`

Comment: У меня сейчас под рукой нет компьютера. Я использовал онлайн интерпретатор. Может проблема в этом? Там у меня выдает результат ['1', '2', '3']

Comment: Да, действительно ошибка есть. Правильной командой будет    '123'.split(" ")

Answer (score 0):

Вот еще как вариант(если я правильно понял условие):

```
s = '1234567'
s = s.replace(s[3], "") #например "3й", правда это если несколько одинаковых символов будет, удалятся все
```

Answer (score -1):

Используйте replace с указание индекса:

```py
st = '12345'
print(st.replace(st[1], ''))
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Заодно поясните, что дополнительно нового в вашем ответе по сравнению с [этим ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1083285)? Если ничего, то пожалуйста удалите это сообщение.